# docker neo4j import files from another container

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am running neo4j community in a docker container.  I would like to import a .graphml (just an .xml file really) from another container.  I've tried the approach outlined [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/import/web-apis/) but without success.  Can this be done and if so how?

Comment: Your link does not mention graphml. Did you mean [this](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/import/graphml/)? Also, make sure you are relying on the documentation for your version of neo4j.

Comment: I've used the .graphml import when the file was available in the neo4j `import` directory.  The use-case here is that the file is the neo4j is running in one container and the file is generated in another.  The web API doesn't explicitly work for graphml but I had hoped I could use the xml remote import.